# Slow network is detected. netdna.bootstrapcdn error on console

Tags: google-chrome

My website is showing following error on console.How to solve this.

> Slow network is detected. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more
>   details. Fallback font will be used while loading:
>   http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the following chrome flag to  Unknown will prevent that message appearing on dev-console :

chrome://flags/#force-effective-connection-type

Override Effective Connection type ->Unknown.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)